# Can't use a method from my React Native Android Module

Tags: javascript, java, android, module, react-native

I want to make a react native module for Android but I can't access the module's methods. It throws the error "Undefined is not an object". What is wrong with my code?

In this case, I want to call the foo() method when I press a button.

My code is presented below:

TestModule.java

```
public class TestModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    public TestModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "TestModule";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void foo(){

    }
}
```

TestPackage.java

```
public class TestPackage implements ReactPackage{
    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();

        modules.add(new TestModule(reactContext));

        return modules;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

MyApplication.java

```
    public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

        private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
            @Override
            public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
            return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
            }

            @Override
            protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
            return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
                new MainReactPackage(),            
                new TestPackage(), //Added my TestPackage
                new ToastPackage()
            );
            }
        };

        @Override
        public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
            return mReactNativeHost;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
        }
    }
```

index.android.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
AppRegistry,
StyleSheet,
Text,
View,
Button,
NativeModules,
} from 'react-native';

var toast = NativeModules.Toast;
var test = NativeModules.TestModule;

export default class RNModuleTest extends Component {

    showToast(){
        toast.show("Hello from toast", toast.LONG);
    }

    showTest(){
        test.foo();
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Button title="Toast" onPress={this.showToast}/>
            <Button title="testModule" onPress={this.showTest} />

        </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure to clean and rebuild gradle project, your code seems fine

Comment: How do I clean the gradle project? Do I erase something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

At the TestPackage.java file, the `createJSModules()` and `createViewManagers()` methods should be returning `Collections.emptyList()` instead of returning `null`.